# How to import data from csv files to SQLite database using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, csv

I'm trying to import some csv files into my sqlite database.

I tried using this [CP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export) example, but stuck with the exception

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

I tried installing the ODBC driver for SQL server, but with no success. The exception is not resolved.

Is there anything that I miss? Or can I follow a different method for this?

Comment: Can we see any code...?

Comment: Please follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export). I use the same code without any changes.

Comment: @ShehanThamel he is using SQLite which is not quite the same as SQL. But it's a good link to get the idea of how you can do it

Comment: I also use SQLite as my database. I'm really trying to copy some data of 5 tables from one PC to another PC, that have the same database structure on both ends.

Comment: Consider using LinqToExcel library to fetch data from excel. Here is a good example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659643/Csharp-Query-Excel-and-CSV-Files-Using-LinqToExcel